# How to join a cube to a cylinder

Tags: modeling, topology, bevel

I want to join a cube to a cylinder, or more accurately, i have extruded a section of the cylinder to make a rectangular part.
[image]

I now want to replace all the sharp edges with bevels, but i'm having problems with the corner where the cube and sphere merge.

[image]

How can i archieve bevels that dont clip into each other here?
Since i am modelling from a reference, i can't really make away with the corner as it's also present in the real counterpart.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try this topology:

[image]

[image]

Rounder bevel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does look promising, but i would like an actual bevel in there

Comment: this is a kind of bevel, except the edges are pretty close so it tends to sharpen the edges, do you mean you want it less sharp? In that case you just need to push the edges away from each others